# Submit an .ppam add-in to Microsoft AppSource?

Tags: powerpoint, add-in, appsource

I have written a **VBA** macro for **Microsoft PowerPoint** (including a custom ribbon tab) and saved it as .ppam file.

Is it possible to submit the .ppam file to **Microsoft AppSource**?

I have read that an Office add-in consists of two parts: the manifest (an XML file) and the web app but I am asking if these files are maybe already included in or generated from the .ppam so that it could also be used for submission.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

VBA add-ins and what MS calls Apps are two different things. As far as I know, MS doesn't accept VBA (ie, PPAM) add-ins for the app store.

Comment: Do you know if this is anywhere explicitly documented? And I guess it's not possible to convert a .ppam file into XML manifest and web app e.g. via a 3rd party tool?

Comment: Microsoft seems all about telling you what you *can* upload to the store, not what you can't, but have a look here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/add-on-submissions I don't see anything about Office VBA add-ins. OTOH, they now accept MSI and EXE installers, so maybe an MSI/EXE that installs your add-in into PPT might fly.  Converting a PPAM/PPTM to a web app is a total non-starter. PPT web apps have very limited functionality.

Comment: I have just checked the [JavaScript API for PowerPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint?view=powerpoint-js-preview) and the functionality seems really to be very limited.

Comment: @FrankZielen Exactly. It has its advantages when it works for what you want to do, but when it doesn't ... oh well.